# libxml2 2.8 on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, libxml2

I need to get libxml2 2.8+ working in my Ubuntu 10.04 environment and I can't seem to find the version I need for the OS. I could upgrade to 12.04 as it has 2.8 installed by default, but that's more work than I want to deal with.

Is there any way I can install libxml2 2.8+ on Ubuntu 10.04? Using the source and bundler?

I found this post, but I'm not sure how to accomplish it on Ubuntu:

[WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.7.3, but has dynamically loaded 2.7.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452380/warning-nokogiri-was-built-against-libxml-version-2-7-3-but-has-dynamically-lo/11452381#11452381)

I have downloaded and untared the source, what's my next steps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, try apt-get with the version you'd like.  For instance (and I haven't looked if 2.8.0 is even in the default 10.4 Ubuntu repos)

```
$ sudo apt-get install libxml2=2.8.0
```

but use that with caution as it can cause dependency downgrades and APT problems. You have the source, and that's usually a better place to be.

The source package is built around GNU autotools

```
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make check
$# if all is ok, then
$ sudo make install
```

For options and more control over features, start with

```
$ ./configure --help
```

and look to see if you'd need things like *--with-run-debug* etcetera.

For autotools source builds, you may have to dig around for the development headers required for some dependencies.   ./configure usually informs you of what is missing, then go look for **-dev** versions of the packages.  You won't need it, as you have the source tree, but as an example *apt-get install libxml2-dev*

The default installation top level for apt-get is usually **/usr**, and for GNU autotools, and source builds, it is usually **/usr/local**.  This is a good thing, but can make looking for libraries (from a human point of view) a little trickier, until you get used to the lay of the land.

Comment: I was able to make install even though I got an error during the check: 

'Error for ./test/errors/name2.xml failed
File ./test/errors/name2.xml generated an error'.

That file looks to just be filled with garbage foo data. Now, in /usr/local/lib I have libxml2.so.2.9.0, what needs to be done to get the system using the new version?

Comment: $ sudo ldconfig will reset the link loader cache.